# Get custom header from ajax response

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

[image][image]i use nodejs with express as rest api, on client side i use jQuery (ajax) for http request.
When user perform login request the server return user object as body and x-auth token in header.
The problem is for some reason i don't see the x-auth header in response data.
Server side code:

```
//POST api/login
app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {

  var body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password'])
  console.log(body)
  var user;
  User.findByCredentials(body.email, body.password).then((result) => {
    user = result
    return user.generateAuthToken()
  }).then((token) => {
    // as you see i put the token here as header, and it is not null i 
    // made debugging.
    res.status(200).header('x-auth', token).send(user) 
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send('Unauthorized')
  })

})
```

Client side code:

```
let loginRequest = {
        "email":username,
        "password":password
      }
      loginRequest = JSON.stringify(loginRequest)
      console.log(loginRequest)
      var res = $.ajax({
        url:"http://192.168.1.22:3000/api/login",
        method: "POST",
        data: loginRequest,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(user, status, response){
          console.log('Login success :'+status);
          console.log(user.fullName +", role: "+user.role)
         //i try to print all the headers here but it not contain the x-auth 
          console.log(`${response.getAllResponseHeaders()}`)

        },
        error: function(e){
          console.log("login error, status: "+e.status +" message : 
                                              "+e.responseText);
        }
      })
```

When i print all the headers : `response.getAllResponseHeaders()` 
the result is : `content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8`

I also have android client for this api and in android i do have the x-auth header.
Do i miss something in ajax ?

Comment: Does your response have the `HttpOnly` header?

Comment: @Taplar you mean in `success` method on client side?

Comment: I mean the response.  Check the response in your browsers developer tools using the Network tab.  You can see all the raw headers in there for both the request and response.  You can also use this to verify that there is indeed an `x-auth` header.

Comment: @Taplar i added screen shot of dev tools and it does have the header in response, but how to obtain it in the code?

Comment: Ok, i don't see the HttpOnly in there, so have you tried using `response.getResponseHeader('x-auth')`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getResponseHeader  specifically?

Comment: @Taplar yes it returns null

Comment: Wait, are you showing the headers from the OPTIONS request?  You need to look at the ones for the POST

Comment: @Taplar take a look at second image i added, why i have 2 requests one OPTION and second is the POST ?

Comment: @Taplar no, the screen shot with headers is for POST

Comment: When you make a web request, it will in some cases make an OPTIONS request first, in order to determine if the server will accept your request for processing.  This is related to CORS restrictions and other security concerns.

Comment: Not sure then why it's not coming back.

Comment: @Taplar it is not a cookie you can see how i add it on the server side. Its very weird that i can't access the header.

Comment: @Taplar I also tried to use `axios` for the request but have same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hundreds of tries i found that because it was CORS request, i was needed add  `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` to `res.header` at server side

full code for express middleware in server :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'x-auth'); //added this line
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, headers, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, contentType, Accept, x-auth");
  next()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is fine with your code and the problem is about cross-origin-resource-sharing. Before you make a post request to `url:"http://192.168.1.22:3000/api/login"`, your browser checks if there is access for an incoming request from outside in your API (server), if yes, then your request will be sent to the server. In order to enable an incoming request from outside, you should use [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Comment: To be honest, I did not see the first answer but it's a delight to find the answer. Cool.